# Pentaho spoon : couldn't convert String to number : non-numeric character found at position 1 for value [100]

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have as input a text file, all are in String. To insert to my DB, I changed some columns' data types (String to Integer) via `"select value"-"meta Data"`.
And here's the message of error :

> couldn't convert String to number : non-numeric character found at
>   position 1 for value [100]

I don't understand even with this message. The value 100 is indeed in String and I'm trying to change it to Integer...

Comment: Try trimming the fields first, there might be unprintable characters before the 100. Also, check the format mask. Perhaps it's expecting numbers with periods or similar. Try # for integers.

Comment: The prob was indeed with format mask, thanks a lot !

Answer (score -1):

on your select values step,try adding the number symbol (#) on the format column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAob9.png)